# Xiao ESP32-c3 abnormal behavior, Arduino IDE

Tags: upload, esp32

I've designed two devices to work on the Xiao Esp32-c3 processor. I literally can't explain any of this, but I'm going to try to convey the information.

One of the devices has resistors to ground on D4 and D9, which are also connected to switches. So far, I've been simply trying to read the switches, but the device also has IR receiver functionality. Now here's the kicker: without those resistors in place, I'm able to upload a sketch, or it seems to upload the sketch, occasionally it works, mostly it doesn't. But here's the main issue. The minute I had a problem with the first one, now every sketch I try to upload to any XIAO esp32-c3 is wonky in some way or another. I've got an IR receiver sketch that has always worked, and somehow the board or program now misinterprets the IR signal. Half the time, Serial output is available at the Monitor, other times it isn't.

I seriously can't make heads or tails of this, I only know that once one single esp32-c3 messed up, every single other one of them that I try to use also has a problem.

The problem is too loose for me to understand what is going on.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please try again in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"One of the devices has resistors to ground on D4 and D9"*. GPIO9 (D9 in Xiao) along with GPIO2 and GPIO8 of ESP32-C3 are strapping pins, GPIO9 has an internal pull-up resistor in order for the chip be able to boot from the SPI Flash chip. Read page 11 of [ESP32-C3 datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf).

Comment: I've managed to get the pin on GPIO9 (D9) working. Don't ask me how. Maybe the larger resistor I added to ground was enough to overcome the internal pullup. As for D4, I have no idea. As a hack, I tried using D0 as in INPUT pin (worst case scenario I'd add a jumper to that pin), and I'm having the same issue there, a low state digitalRead() no matter what voltage is applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

After writing a simple matrix to check all the digital I/O pins for input, it turns out some of the pins are defined incorrectly somewhere. For now, I've got it working by referring to pin 4 as pin 6.